# How to create filter in mobile Gmail?

Tags: gmail, filter

Opening a message on my phone/tablet and I want to create a filter for that message but I cannot see where to do it. The same thing can be found from the top right menu when using the web version of Gmail.

Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 20):

As far as I know, the GMail app and the mobile version of GMail does not have any way to add filters. You will have to use the Desktop/full version of GMail to create filters.

Comment: Will filters created in desktop Gmail be effective in mobile version? Creating them in desktop isn't a problem. The question is, if mobile version will respect them?

Comment: @trejder yes it will work in mobile version.

Comment: @PeacefulWarrior I'd say completely opposite. At least in my version of Gmail all the filters defined in PC/desktop version are completely ignored by mobile version and all the emails that should land in corresponding folders always lands in Inbox, if mobile version of Gmail is first to see them.

Comment: @trejder I guess you need to select option - "Skip the Inbox (Archive it)"  along with your filter criteria while defining filters.

Comment: @trejder Try removing categories too. Your comment is correct.

Answer (score 15):

Direct way, no. Workaround, yes. Click the menu (three dots) in your stock Android browser or Chrome, and check `Desktop Site`.

EDIT: There is one extra step - the URL is still pointing to mobile version of Gmail. Just change it to mail.google.com and it works. (Last verified June 2020)

Comment: The current version of web Gmail gives a mobile version of the app even when you request a desktop version.

Comment: Because the url is already pointing to mobile site.
After you check Request Desktop Site, and the page reloads, the update the url to https://mail.google.com in the same tab. Still works.